# Launcher replaced by gray area in Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: unity, virtualbox, launcher

I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 desktop i386 on Virtualbox 4.2.12 on Windows 7. After enabling 3d acceleration in settings, launcher (left side application pane\taskbar) did not appear.  So I disabled it and I got like this:

[image]

I ran the command `unity --replace` and the following was shown. The launcher first came into view and immediately disappeared being replaced by the gray area as shown in the above image.

Here is the [output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5771143/) of `unity --replace`

Please offer your assistance in helping me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reset Unity settings.
Type this into your Terminal (press CTRL+ALT+T):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools && dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && setsid unity
```

If unity doesn't correctly restart, then just restart the PC, and it should work again.

Comment: >Reading package lists... Done<br>
Building dependency tree       <br>
Reading state information... Done<br>
dconf-tools is already the newest version.<br>
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:<br>
The following packages have unmet dependencies:<br>
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev : Depends: g++-4.7 (= 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) but it is not installable<br>
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).<br>
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$<br>

Comment: @chndn You already have dconf-tools. So just type:
`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && setsid unity`
You also have some problems with some packages. To fix them type: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: It is working thnx (if any problem persisits i will let u know) thanku for your help ..  +1